# is CMake ignoring CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY?

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

I just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744130/1593077), suggesting the use of `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for setting the directory in which library targets are created. Well, this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
# etc. etc.
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "lib/")

cuda_add_library(
    mykernels
    src/kernel_wrappers/kernel1.cu
    src/kernel_wrappers/kernel2.cu)
```

When I `make`, the library `libmyktkernels.a` is created in the main project folder (where my `CMakeFiles.txt` is located), not in the `lib/` subdirectory. Why is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for the static libraries.

`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` applies only to **dynamic** libraries.